# Awk programming: Split large file into smaller ones based on pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

I have a large file input.dat which looks as shown below.

```
kpoint1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
 kpoint2 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
```

I need to Split the file into 2 smaller ones as below

`kpoint1.dat`:

```
kpoint1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
```

and `kpoint2.dat`:

```
kpoint1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
```

I wrote a small script to do that. The script is shown below.

```
for j in {1..2} 
do
    awk '$1=="kpoint'$j'" {for(i=1; i<=3; i++){getline; print}}' tmp7 >kpoint'$j'.dat
done
```

The script creates output files with the desired names. But all the files are empty. Can any one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done entirely in `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /kpoint[0-9]/ { file = $1 ".dat" } {print > file}' file
$ head kpoint*
==> kpoint1.dat <==
kpoint1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000

==> kpoint2.dat <==
 kpoint2 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
```

Awk also supports `> file` for redirection, with some subtle differences (see [GNU awk's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) for more).

Comment: @SruthilLalS.B. Hello, if this answer works for you, please click on the tick mark to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

While [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/916716/295286) is the simplest, there's several other ways without the use of awk.

#### Perl

The approach with awk is basically that we write to a specific filename, and alter that filename if and only if we encounter kpoint in the beginning of the line. Same approach can be done with Perl:

```
$ perl -ane '$p=$F[0] if $F[0] =~ /kpoint/;open($f,">>",$p . ".dat"); print $f $_' input.txt
```

Here's how this works:

- `-a` flag allows us to use the special `@F` array of words that have been automatically split from each line of input file. Thus `$F[0]` refers to the first word, just like `$1` in awk
- `$p=$F[0] if $F[0] =~ /kpoint/` is meant to alter `$p` ( which is meant to be prefix variable ) if and only if `kpoint` is in the line. The improvement to that pattern match could be `/^ *kpoint/`
- at each iteration we open for **appending** a file which has name `$p` joined with `.dat` string; note that appending part is important. If you want to have clear run, you probably want to get rid of old `kpoint` files. If we want the file to always be created fresh and overwritten, then we can reqrite original command as:

  ```
  $ perl -ane 'if ($F[0] =~ /kpoint/){$p=$F[0]; open($f,">",$p . ".dat")}; print $f $_' input.txt
  ```
- And finally `print $f $_` just prints to whatever filename we have open.

#### split

From your example it appears that each entry consists of 5 lines. If that's constant, we can split the file that way, without relying on pattern matching with `split`. Specifically this command:

```
$ split --additional-suffix=".dat" --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 5 input.txt  kpoint
```

In this command options are as follows:

- `--additional-suffix=".dat"` is the static `.dat` suffix that will be added to each file created
- `--numeric-suffixes=1` will allow us adding changing numbers starting at 1 to each filename
- `-l 5` will allow splitting the input file every 5 lines
- `input.txt` is the file we're trying to split
- `kpoint` will be the static filename prefix

And here how this works in practice:

```
$ split --additional-suffix=".dat" --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 5 input.txt  kpoint                                                                        
$ cat kpoint01.dat                                                                                                                                    
kpoint1 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
$ cat kpoint02.dat                                                                                                                                    
 kpoint2 :       0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
  band No.  band energies     occupation 
      1     -52.8287      2.00000
      2     -52.7981      2.00000
      3     -52.7981      2.00000
```

Optionally, we could also add `--suffix-length=1` to keep the length of each numeric suffix shorter like `kpoint1` instead of `kpoint01`, but that might be a problem if you have large number of `kpoint`s.

#### alternative awk

This one is similar to [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/916716/295286), except here we use different pattern match as well as different approach of creating the filename variable via `sprintf()`

```
$ awk '/^\ *kpoint/{f=sprintf("%s.dat",$1)};{print > f}' input.txt
```

#### Python

While `awk` and `split` approaches are shorter, other tools such as Python are well suited for text processing, and we can use those to implement more verbose but working solutions.

The script below does exactly that, and it operates on the idea of looking backwards into the list of lines that we save. The script keeps saving lines, until it encounters `kpoint` at the beginning of the line, which means we've reached a new entry, and which also means we need to write previous entry to its respective file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def write_entry(pref,line_list):
    # this function writes the actual file for each entry
    with open(".".join([pref,"dat"]),"w") as entry_file:
        entry_file.write("".join(line_list))

def main():
    prefix = ""
    old_prefix = ""
    entry=[]
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            # if we encounter kpoint string, that's a signal
            # that we need to write out the list of things 
            if line.strip().startswith('kpoint'):
                prefix=line.strip().split()[0]
                # This if statement counters special case
                # when we just started reading the file
                if not old_prefix:
                    old_prefix = prefix
                    entry.append(line)
                    continue
                write_entry(old_prefix,entry)
                old_prefix = prefix
                entry=[]
            # Keep storing lines. This works nicely after old 
            # entry has been cleared out. 
            entry.append(line)
    # since we're looking backwards, we need one last call
    # to write last entry when input file has been closed
    write_entry(old_prefix,entry)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

#### Pure Bash

Almost the same idea  as the Perl approach - we keep writing everything to specific filename and alter the filename only when we find line with `kpoint` in it.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line;
do
    case "$line" in
        # We found next entry. Use word-splitting to get
        # filename into fname variable, and truncate that filename
        *kpoint[0-9]*) read fname trash <<< $line  && 
                       echo "$line" > "$fname".dat ;;
        # That's just a line within entry. Append to 
        # current working file
        *) echo "$line" >> "$fname".dat ;;
    esac
done < "$1"

# Just in case there are trailing lines that weren't processed
# in while loop, append them to last filename
[ -n "$line" ] && echo "$line" >> "$fname".dat ;
```